# Clickable words inside of TextView Android

Tags: java, android, android-widget, textview, android-textattributes

I have a textview that contains hashtags ex. `#first #second #third`. My question is how can I detect which hashtag is clicked so I can perform some action - eg. make toast of the word.
Is this possible using TextView widget? Should I use some other widget istead?

**UPDATE**

I found my solution using [this example](https://zunostudios.com/blog/development/176-how-to-implment-hashtags-and-callouts-in-android). Hope it will help others in the future!

Answer (score 12):

You can use spannable string to achieve this:

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Your string");
String[] words = ss.split(" ");
for(final String word : words){
   if(word.startsWith("#")){
     ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
        //use word here to make a decision 
    }
    };
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, ss.indexOf(word), ss.indexOf(word) + word.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  }
}


TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
textView.setText(ss);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: thanks @vipul 
and to get the clicked word you can use this inside onClick : 


Spanned sp = (Spanned) ((TextView)textView).getText();
                           int start = sp.getSpanStart(this);
                           int end = sp.getSpanEnd(this);
                           String word = sp.subSequence(start, end).toString();

Comment: `SpannableString` doesn't have `split` and `indexOf` methods